# How to display how many times each records in a table used by other table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query, below are two tables that **tbl_tag** and **tbl_tag_usedby**. I want to show how much of each record in **tbl_tag** used by record in **tbl_tag_usedby**.

[image]

Here is a query that I use:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(u.tagid) AS totale FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_tag_usedby u ON u.tagid = t.id AND t.status =1 GROUP BY u.tagid
```

and the results are as below:

[image]

In this case the record id from 2 to 6 do not appear in the query results, I want record id from 2 to 6 are also shown and on the field "totale" its value is 0.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does tbl_tag_usedby contains tagid=2,3,4...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(t.id) AS totale FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_tag_usedby u ON u.tagid = t.id AND t.status =1 GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
t.*, COUNT(t.id) AS totale 

FROM tbl_tag t 

LEFT JOIN tbl_tag_usedby u ON u.tagid = t.id
where t.status =1 
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       COUNT(t.id) AS totale
FROM    tbl_tag a 
           LEFT JOIN tbl_tag_usedby b 
              ON b.tagid = a.id
WHERE  a.status = 1 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight Correction: This works perfect for me replace `COUNT(t.id)` with `COUNT(u.id)`

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(u.id) AS totale  
FROM tbl_tag t 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_tag_usedby u ON u.tagid = t.id
where t.status =1 
GROUP BY t.id
```